# Extract main domain from URL using Shell/Python/Perl

Tags: python, perl, shell, url

I know it seems this question has been asked and answered, but there are more complicated situation to consider.

I list some situations here:

http:// news.yahoo.com/test -> yahoo.com

http:// www.yahoo.com/test -> yahoo.com

http:// sports.sina.com.cn/test -> sina.com.cn

http:// news.yahoo.co.jp/test -> yahoo.co.jp

http:// subdomain.evisu.jp/test -> evisu.jp

http:// cs.stanford.edu/test -> stanford.edu

http:// eecs.tsinghua.edu.cn/test -> tsinghua.edu.cn

http:// math.u-tokyo.ac.jp/test -> u-tokyo.ac.jp

Actually there are more complicated situation, but let's not discuss the situation below.

http:// www.jx.cn/test -> jx.cn

http:// www.ecjtu.jx.cn/test -> ecjtu.jx.cn

Comment: try echo "http:// news.yahoo.com/test" | cut -f2- -d "." | cut -f1 -d "/"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module on cpan to parse those strings and extract hostnames:

```
use URI;
while(<>) {
    my $uri = URI->new($_);
    my $host = $uri->host;
}
```

And if you need to get rid of the first subdomain, just use string splitting. Something like:

```
my @parts = split /\./, $host;
unshift @parts if @parts > 2;
my $newHost = join ".", @parts;
```